# the resource "" could not be resolved  in design time

Tags: silverlight, resources, styles, app.xaml

My resource  merged in App.xaml. but in design mode not found

in Run time it found and work correctly

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="Assets/Styles/Main.xaml" />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

Style="{StaticResource pnlRibbon}" the resource "pnlRibbon" could not be resolved  in design time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it been solved with add this code to the .csproj file

```
   <ApplicationDefinition Include="App.xaml">
      <Generator>MSBuild:Compile</Generator>
      <SubType>Designer</SubType>
    </ApplicationDefinition>
```

Comment: not work for me. My .csproj file alreay has this code, but I still get the error

Answer (score 2):

Use this syntax:

```
<ResourceDictionary Source="projectName;component/Assets/Styles/Main.xaml" />
```

Comment: thank you , i use this suntax but it not worked. in previous it's worked correctly

Comment: slight mod to this answer had it working for me:

<ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/ProjectName;component/Themes\Generic.xaml"/>

Comment: @Yama moto: ,,, are comma separators for optional arguements. This is a standard declaration (AFAIK)